# Corona SDK native.webview(): how to submit HTML form to local SQLite database?

Tags: html, ios, sqlite, coronasdk

In Corona SDK I have a native.webview() contains HTML form

how can I submit the form to local SQLite database (which is stored in system.DocumentsDirectory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't a way for a webView to communicate with the Corona SDK app other than getting an event when tapping on a link.

Rob